# my redirect in a grails 2.3.4 controller isn't redirecting every time

Tags: grails, filtering

I am using Grails 2.3.4 and I have an app that when the user logs in for the first time it will go and check if the user is in the session, if not then it will go and check if the user is in the database, if not then it will go and create the user. This works as intended.

The issue is that for whatever reason when the session expires it should go and reload the credentials but the code is not redirecting correctly.
I check to see if the user is in the database and if not then else:

```
def filters = {
.....
} else
  redirect controller: "admin", action: "loadingCredentials"
  return true
}
```

Which does fire and takes you into the admin controller which then has:

```
def loadingCredentials(){
...
render(view:'/loadingCredentials', model: model)
log.info("[10] testing")
}
```

this render log.info [10] will appear in the terminal window but the loadingCredentials model never appears.

What am I missing? It works correctly on the first time the user comes to the app and also when you click a separate button to refresh the credentials but the bug happens when the session expires it does not refresh the credentials.

Comment: You'll have to provide more code than that. Upload a minimal project on GitHub that produces the same bug and share the link.

Comment: @SaqibAhmed it would be impossible to make a project similar on GitHub. The range of the project is very wide.